# How to get owner:group name of a file/directory with perl?

Tags: linux, perl, uid

There is a great method to output permissions on Linux and AIX:

```
0:root@SERVER:/root # perl -e 'printf "chmod %04o %s\n", (stat)[2] & 07777, $_ for @ARGV' /home      
chmod 0755 /home
0:root@SERVER:/root #
```

But how to output owner:group? ex.:

```
0:root@SERVER:/root # perl SOMEMAGIC /home
chown bin:bin /home
0:root@SERVER:/root #
```

**UPDATE**: currently I almost figured it out, **only help needed that if there is a symlink, it will give root:root**. It should give the owner:group of the symlink!

```
perl -e '$uid = (stat)[4], $_ for @ARGV; $owner = getpwuid($uid); $gid = (stat)[5], $_ for @ARGV; $group = getgrgid($gid); print "chown $owner:$group \"@ARGV\"\n"' FILENAMEHERE
```

**UPDATE2**: with lstat, it works!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) to get the uid/gid, and [`getpwnam`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/getpwnam.html)/[`getgrnam`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/getgrnam.html) to convert those into names.

If symlinks are involved you might get better results by using `lstat` instead of `stat`:

```
perl -e '$uid = (lstat)[4], $_ for @ARGV; $owner = getpwuid($uid); $gid = (lstat)[5], $_ for @ARGV; $group = getgrgid($gid); print "chown $owner:$group \"@ARGV\"\n"' FILENAMEHERE
```

Comment: tried to figure it out myself, Q updated, any hint for that? :)

Comment: Thanks! updating your answer